# Text Vanishes from Text field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, uitextfield, flutter-layout

I have to take readings like numbers, as shown in screen shot, problem is that text vanishes from the textfeild, i know it is because of the fontsize, but i couldn't figure out solution yet.[image: Screen Shot]

just as i have uploaded picture, let us just see textField  of systolic, when i have entered 123 it appeared shown in next pic.

[image: Second Screen shot]

but when i have entered 4 digits like 1234 it vanished, shown in next pic.

[image: Third ScreenShot]

code for textfield,

```
Container(
                      width: 49,
                      height: 40,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 15, left: 7, right: 5, bottom: 5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[800]),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                      ),
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: '000',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF000080),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          //labelText: '000',
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF000080),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    )
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just removed padding from container and it worked